# How does this ideal diode circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

The solution is that the diode at 1 V will be forward biased while the other two diodes will be reverse biased. This is because the anode of the other two diodes will be 1 V.

The professor showed us what happens when all 3 diodes are reverse biased. He said the anode will be 5 V for the 3 diodes. I was wondering why the 5 V will interact with the diodes when they are all reverse biased and how come the 5 V does not affect the diodes when only the 1 V diode is forward biased.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that **if you assume** that all of the diodes are reverse-biased then their anodes must be at 5V.

However, that would imply that the forward voltage across the bottom diode is 4V. We usually assume that any normal diode would in fact be forward-biased with 4V across it. So, what we conclude is that the assumption that all diodes are reverse-biased can not be true.

When solving problems like this for non-linear elements we often make an assumption about whether the diode is forward or reverse biased, then we solve for the diode voltage and current. If we **assume** that a diode is reverse biased but we find that the voltage across it would be greater than its knee voltage (usually about 0.7V) then we know that the assumption is wrong and the diode must in fact be forward biased.